# How do FIR filters roll offs with no poles

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response

FIR filters only have zeros, how does it work like a filter with rolloffs if there are no poles?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. Why do you think a pole is needed for a filter's response to roll off? Also, technically speaking, FIR filters do have poles as well; they are just all located at $z=0$.

Comment: with all poles located at z=0, how do you place the cutoff frequency?

Comment: By placing the zeros accordingly. The poles at $z=0$ push the transfer function up, and the zeros pin it down. It's the same principle as with IIR filters, just that you don't have the flexibility to arbitrarily place the poles.